# No sound recorded using iPhone5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, avcapturedevice

I am using below code to capture sound. It works fine on all devices expect iPhone5 ios7.

Please help.

```
AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

NSError *error = nil;

AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];

if (audioInput)
{
    [CaptureSession addInput:audioInput];
}
```

Comment: Did you check whether the error is set?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the below code in before getting the `AVCaptureDevice` instance

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

UInt32 doChangeDefault = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(doChangeDefault), &doChangeDefault);
```

Comment: AudioSessionSetProperty is deprecated in iOS7